# Implementing 'Save As' popup window when user try to download file

Tags: javascript, html, grails, gsp, savefiledialog

I have a Grails application. When user press a download button the audio clip is downloaded.

```
 <g:link action="download" id="${sessionsInstance?.id}" class="btn btn-xs">
     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
     <g:message code="com.ef.session.download" default="Download" />
 </g:link>
```

Currently, I have specified path in code and download the file in that path. But I want that when user press `download` button a `Save As` popup window should be generated allowing user to specify the path where user wants to store that file not the one specified in code. Such As:

[image]

Kindly guide me that how may I achieve this as I am dealing with this for the first time.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change the clients (Browser) download path from the server side (your Grails application).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is something which is specific to browser and cannot be done thru code.

For eg. If you have the latest firefox.

Go to options -> General tab. See an option of "Always ask me where to save files"

[image]

Comment: you are right ... But we will have to do something at our end too (in code) to generate pop-up window etc

Comment: If the option "Always ask me where to save files" shown on this screenshot is checked then Firefox will give you that popup. There is no code to be written for that.

Comment: Currently I simply get the url and download the file in the specified location. No popup indeed

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you are trying to do. But would you mind pasting your controller action code for download. It might give me some idea on what you are asking. If it is relating to forcing a file download in grails then this might be of some help: http://lalitagarw.blogspot.com/2014/03/grails-forcing-file-download.html